# Pass variable %s to href with Google App Engine

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, jinja2

I am trying to pass my variable id to the href

```
   {% set id = p.key().id() %}

<a href="/blog/editpost/%s" % id > Edit Post</a>
```

But it is showing up as /blog/editpost/%s instead of /blog/edit/93090902902 where the number is the post id.

I know how to do it using ?postId = and also

```
<a href="/blog/editpost/{{p.key().id()}}"> Edit Post </a>
```

But with that method I have to get the last thing in the url path in my python file. I want to instead get the id request object.

What I am asking here is how can I use %s to send my variable id instead of using some other way of sending it?

Comment: I'm pretty unclear what you're asking here ... I would have suggested `<a href="/blog/editpost/{{p.key().id()}}"> Edit Post </a>` but you seem to already know how to do that.  I guess what I don't understand is _why_ that isn't an acceptable solution.

Comment: I am just trying to learn something different such as how do I pass the %s into my html?   Because in my python method I want to be able to get id = self.request.get('id') rather than having to get the path which I already how to do. And I also don't want to do it by making the url ?id= which also I know how to do.

Comment: do you mean `href="{{'/blog/editpost/%s' % id}}"`?  (with your previous `set`)

Comment: That works! Thanks for your help and responding so quickly!

Comment: or `<a href="/blog/editpost/{{ id }}"> Edit Post </a>`?

Comment: Thanks for your help GAEfan.